# Multiple consumers with the same name in different projects subscribed to the same queue

Tags: masstransit

We have `UserCreated` event that gets published from UserManagement.Api. I have two other Apis, Payments.Api and Notification.Api that should react to that event.

In both Apis I have `public class UserCreatedConsumer : IConsumer<UserCreated>` (so different namespaces) but only one queue (on SQS) gets created for both consumers.

What is the best way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't share your configuration, but if you're using:

```cs
x.AddConsumer<UserCreatedConsumer>();
```

As part of your MassTransit configuration, you can [specify an InstanceId](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/#endpoint-definition) for that consumer to generate a unique endpoint address.

```cs
x.AddConsumer<UserCreatedConsumer>()
    .Endpoint(x => x.InstanceId = "unique-value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Every separate service (not an instance of the same service) needs to have a different queue name of the receiving endpoint, as described in the docs:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queue-name-per-service-type", e =>
{
    // rest of the configuration
});
```

It's also mentioned in the [common mistakes](http://masstransit-project.com/troubleshooting/common-gotchas.html#sharing-a-queue) article.

Comment: If you are hand coding receive endpoints, then yes, this approach would work. However, developers new to MassTransit commonly use `ConfigureEndpoints`, and no longer explicitly create receive endpoints.

Comment: The principle is still the same, every service needs its own endpoint. I normally prefer keeping the endpoint name in the configuration, as I might have other things like monitoring dashboards, which must be linked to specific queue names, subscriptions, etc. It's hard to impossible to do it with implicit configuration, which I don't control.

Comment: Fair enough, the conventions are static though, so the endpoint names are consistent based upon consumer/saga names. Anyway, good points.