# Is it possible for multiple consumers mass transit and azure service bus

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, masstransit

I have a scenario to update two related tables on a button click event.

I am using mass transit with azure service bus

so the requirement is to publish messages and have multiple consumer service instances receive them.

I have written consumer to update one table. Is it possible for multiple consumers to listen to one end point and update respective table.
Can i get some guidance on the configuration or a working sample?

Sample answer to start with the implementation

Comment: Also, duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69450725/1882).

Answer (score 1):

A single consumer (same namespace + type name) can be used across multiple services by specifying an `InstanceId` when registering the consumer.

```cs
x.AddConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer, SubmitOrderConsumerDefinition>()
    .Endpoint(x => x.InstanceId = "something-unique-per-instance");
```

MassTransit will then append that value to the default endpoint name.

Comment: ,my controller publosh an event say  await _publishEndpoint.Publish<MyCreatedEvent>(
                new MyCreatedEvent
                {                   
                    Code = a.Code,
                    Description = a.Description
                });.                      is it possible for the consume method to accept event   Consume(ConsumeContext<MyCreatedEvent> context)

Comment: i have seen all consume method accepts input param as message .Hence i get the query Can i use Consume method to Consume(ConsumeContext<MyCreatedEvent> context)  instead of Consume(ConsumeContext<MyMessage> context)